# Ether.js websocket pending transactions for a particular address

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I’m utilizing ether.js for my project and have established a Websocket connection through Infura. I couldn’t find a straightforward way to directly listen to transactions for a specific address. As a workaround, I’ve incorporated a filter within the pending hook. This approach functions to some extent, the performance isn’t optimal, and for a while only. Because each transaction are requested within the hook, the daily request limit is rapidly exceeded.

If anyone has insights on how to properly configure a Websocket connection to listen to pending transactions for a specific address, I’d greatly appreciate the help!

```
const wsProvider = new InfuraWebSocketProvider('sepolia', API_KEY);

export const initTransactionsListener = (address: string): WebSocketListener => {
    wsProvider.on('pending', async (tx: string) => {
        const transaction = await wsProvider.getTransaction(tx);

        if ([null, undefined].includes(transaction)) {
            return;
        }

        const { from, to } = transaction;

        if (![from, to].includes(address)) {
            return;
        }

        console.log('Transaction', transaction)
    });
    
    return {
        destroy: async () => await wsProvider.destroy()
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will solve your problem. Modify to fit into your use

```
       provider.on("pending", (txHash) => {
              
              const address = "address you want to listen for trx";

            provider.getTransaction(txHash).then(function (transaction) {
                //console.log(transaction?.from);

                const from = transaction?.from;
                const to = transaction?.to;
                const value =transaction?.value;

                if (from === address) {
                    process.stdout.write(`[${(new Date).toLocaleTimeString()}] Outgoing transfer: ${value} ETH to ${to} \r`);
                    //console.log(`Outgoing transfer: ${value} ETH to ${to}`);
                } else if (to === address) {
                    //console.log(`Incoming transfer: ${value} ETH from ${from}`);
                    process.stdout.write(`[${(new Date).toLocaleTimeString()}] Incoming transfer: ${value} ETH to ${from} \r`);
                }else {
                console.log('Unknown transfer'); 
}
            
                console.log(`[${(new Date).toLocaleTimeString()}]  => Monitoring address: ${address}`);

              });
        });
```